# Selenium ExpectedConditions parameter

Tags: selenium

While writing Selenium tests, I noticed in the `ExpectedConditions` class, some methods use only `By` as parameter, some use only `WebElement` as parameter, and some methods have overloaded methods that support both parameters.

- presenceOfElementLocated(final By locator)
- visibilityOf(final WebElement element)
- elementToBeClickable(final By locator)
- elementToBeClickable(final WebElement element)

So my questions are:

1. Why dont all methods use By, WebElement or both?
2. Is there any benefit of using By over WebElement or the other way around?
3. If I use Page Object Model, does it mean I need to maintain both By instance and WebElement instance for the same element on the page?

Source: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's depends on requirements

- `presenceOfElementLocated(final By locator)` :

  *An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible.*

Here you can only use `By` locator because if you have already found `WebElement` then there is nothing make sense to use this `ExpectedConditions` by passing `WebElement`.

- `visibilityOf(final WebElement element)` :

  *An expectation for checking that an element, known to be present on the DOM of a page, is visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.*

Means if you have `WebElement` and you already know this element present on the `DOM` and would not be stale means this wouldn't throw `StaleElementException` due to changing of the page at run time but you doesn't know element is visible or not then use this `ExpectedConditions` by passing `WebElement`.

- `elementToBeClickable(final By locator)` and `elementToBeClickable(final WebElement element)`  :

  *An expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.*

Means if you have `WebElement` and you already know this element present on the `DOM` and would not be stale means this wouldn't throw `StaleElementException` due to changing of the page at run time but you doesn't know element is visible and enable or not then use `elementToBeClickable(final WebElement element)`.

But some time due to ajax or other reason if page would be change during checking `elementToBeClickable(final WebElement element)` `ExpectedConditions` then it couldn't meet with condition due to `StaleElementException` because in `elementToBeClickable(final WebElement element)` condition selenium only check for visibility and enable condition for already found `WebElement` while using `elementToBeClickable(final By locator)` `ExpectedConditions` selenium goes to find element before checking that element is visible and enable to overcome the chance of failure due to `StaleElementException`.

**So this is the benefits of using `By` over `WebElement` Here.**